# speechSynthesis API not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to experiment with [speechSynthesis API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html) with the help of [Eric's blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API?hl=en).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardik4now/W5rS8/) is working fine, meaning there is [no issue with the audio device permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073192/web-speech-api-not-working) for website (correct me if I'm wrong). I made my [own fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zameeramir/LbjmavhL/) but doesn't seems to be working (I mean it is not saying *Hello world*).

Here is my code:

```js
function speak() {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world');
    msg.rate = 0.7;
    msg.pitch = 1;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

```html
<button title="Click to listen" onclick="speak()">
         Say hello world
</button>
```

**Update:** The code is working here as pointed out by [enhzflep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630963/enhzflep) but not in [JSFiddle's editor](http://jsfiddle.net/zameeramir/LbjmavhL/)

Any suggestions, kind folks?

Comment: i still cannot hear anything

Comment: @rash But I can :) I have tried it and seems working on Chrome

Comment: in my case restarting browser helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.Well, the snippet you've posted here on this page works for me, yet the fiddle containing the same code doesn't. However, if you change the 2nd drop-down to `"No wrap - in <head>"` then it's just fine.

This is because jsfiddle wrapped your code into a function that was called when the document loaded, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function speak() {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world');
    msg.rate = 0.7;
    msg.pitch = 1;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
}//]]>  
</script>
```

By doing this, code outside of the `window.onload` handler, including the inline JS in your html can't 'see' your `speak` function.

By changing the drop-down, jsFiddle generates different JS for the iframe that shows your result, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

function speak() {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world');
    msg.rate = 0.7;
    msg.pitch = 1;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
//]]>  

</script>
```